# Create multiple arrays based on frequency of coordinates in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates, frequency

Using JavaScript, I'd like to split one big array of coordinates into smaller arrays based on coinciding points. I am not 100% sure how to write the following in code but it describes what I'm attempting to achieve:

1. Iterate through the array

   `var A = [(1,2)(1,3)(2,3)(9,10)(9,11)(10,11)];`
2. Combine the pairs that contain any matching/identical coordinate points:

   `var B = (1,2)(1,3)(2,3)`

   `var C = (9,10)(9,11)(10,11)`
3. Combine the matching/identical points and create new, smaller arrays from the combinations in point #2

   `var D = [1,2,3]`

   `var E = [9,10,11]`

Can I get help please?

Comment: Is this JavaScript?  Do you mean to use brackets [] everywhere, instead of parentheses () like you did?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to think you will always -- or usually -- be able to break things down this way?  What if you had [[1,2],[1,3],[9,3],[9,10]]?  What is the result you would expect in that case?

Comment: The brackets, [], are for the arrays.

Comment: The big array, var A, doesn't have anything around the individual points. it actually looks like this:
`1 2 1 3 2 3 9 10 9 11 10 11`
However, in the code I've added the parenthesis and comma to create 'coordinates' so that it'd be easier to handle.

Comment: I think you requirements are ambiguous...

Comment: The reason certain points are grouped is because they're related in another part of my code. I'm just stuck on finding the frequency of pairs that are similar and then separating the matching pairs into their own smaller arrays for processing further down the code.

Comment: @missingno One sec, let me add some code, etc to this question that way it presents more data to work with...

Comment: While attempting to parse some code for everyone to review I ended up finding something to work off of. I'm reviewing the code below as that is some awesome work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working answer: http://jsfiddle.net/y3h9L/

OK, so if I understand the requirement A is a one-dimensional array that is assumed to have an even number of elements in x,y pairs.

```
A = [1,2,  1,3,  2,3,  9,10,  9,11,  10,11]
// output should be
[ [1,2,3], [9,10,11] ]

// but if you add an extra pair that links the two halves, say add 2,11
A2 = [1,2,  1,3,  2,3,  9,10,  9,11,  10,11,   2,11]
// then all are related so output should be
[ [1,2,3,9,10,11] ]
```

I've made no effort to pretty-up or optimise the following code, but it works:

```
// single dimensional array of x,y pairs
var A = [1,2,  1,3,  2,3,  9,10,  9,11,  10,11];

// create a working copy of A so that we can remove elements
// and still keep the original A intact.
var workingCopy = A.slice(0, A.length),
    matchedPairs = [],
    currentMatches,
    finalCombinations = [],
    x, y, i, j,
    tempArray;

while (workingCopy.length > 0) {
   currentMatches = [];
   currentMatches.push([workingCopy.shift(),workingCopy.shift()]);

   workingCopyLoop:
   for (x=0,y=1; x < workingCopy.length;) {
      for (i=0; i < currentMatches.length; i++){
         if (workingCopy[x] === currentMatches[i][0]
            || workingCopy[y] === currentMatches[i][1]) {
            currentMatches.push([workingCopy.shift(),workingCopy.shift()]);
            // go back to the beginning of workingCopyLoop
            x=0;
            y=1;
            continue workingCopyLoop;
         }
      }

      x += 2;
      y += 2;
   }   

   matchedPairs.push(currentMatches);
}

for (i=0; i<matchedPairs.length; i++){
   tempArray = [];
   for (j=0; j<matchedPairs[i].length; j++) {
      // I assume you have a new enough version of JS that you have Array.indexOf()
      if (-1 === tempArray.indexOf(matchedPairs[i][j][0]))
         tempArray.push(matchedPairs[i][j][0]);
      if (-1 === tempArray.indexOf(matchedPairs[i][j][1]))
         tempArray.push(matchedPairs[i][j][1]);
   }
   finalCombinations.push(tempArray);
}

for (i=0; i<finalCombinations.length; i++)
   console.log(finalCombinations[i]);

// console.log shows that finalCombinations = [ [1,2,3], [9,10,11] ]
```

If it's not obvious how this works, follow it through with a debugger and/or pencil and paper.

Comment: This worked so well! I've learned several things while studying this code. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: You're welcome. Since you said you were studying my code note that I did some things with the for loop labeled "workingCopyLoop" which I do not recommend for _most_ for loops, but which happened to work out nicely for the way I happened to tackle your problem: (1) I modified the array being iterated over within the loop (shift() removes an array's first item and returns that item), though it worked fine because each time I did it (2) inside the loop I reset the loop counter to 0 to start the loop again, which is also why...

Comment: (3) I omitted the "final expression" in the initial for statement, i.e., the bit just before the closing parenthesis that normally increments the loop counter (since I was fiddling the counters inside the loop). So I guess what I'm saying is that it probably should've been a while loop, but I think (trying to remember back to yesterday) it started out as a more conventional for loop then I realised it wasn't quite doing what I wanted and by the time I had it working I couldn't be bothered changing it to a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

I must say your question is rather unclear, but i think i got it.

In other words what you're saying is:
I have an array containing a bunch of numbers, logically they represent coordinates, it's not that the coordinates are subarrays inside the master array, is just looking them 2 by 2, but it's a linear array.

What you want is something that detects coordinates that are adjacent and generate a new array containing them.

After that you want to go thru the new arrays and generate new arrays containing unique-elements.

Well that's the question, now the answer. First, the second point depends on how far you want to go, i'm thinking it's anormal grid of x,y coordinates, but how adjacent you want to go? The following just applies to the inmediate adjacent, up to 8 points can be adjacent to a single point.

```
[1,1][2,1][3,1]
[1,2][2,2][3,2]
[1,3][2,3][3,3]
```

May that be a representation of the grid, if your master array has the [2,2] coordinate, you want to build an array that begins with that one and all adjacents you find, lets say like master array has [3,2], then you want to add it to the subarray of [2,2].

I'm really not writing the code i'm just gonna explain sorts of algorithm you could use.
To build the second point arrays, lets call them Adjacents Arrays (AA) you could:

First coordinate will always build the first AA
To find adjacents you will cycle thru the master array and perform an "Adjacency Check" to every coordinate which would be: second x == ( first x-1, x or x+1) AND second y == ( first y-1, y or y+1), if it passes then pop/push, if not... next.
In case you finish cycling thru the master array means that AA is complete, and you have to start a new AA with the next coordinate.
Repeat until master array is empty.

Then to create the unique-element-array is quite a simple cycle, i wrote a similar function that does something like that but it creates an array with the element and how many times it appears in the array (instances):

```
function uniqueCnt( ori) { // agroups and counts unique elements of an array, scrubs '' elements
 var res = []; // resulting array, ori parameter stands for original array
 for( let cntA = 0; cntA < ori.length; cntA++) { 
      for( cntB = 0; cntB < res.length; cntB += 2) if( ori[cntA] == res[cntB]) { res[cntB + 1]++; break; } // if it matches means it's another instance then increase that element count
     if( cntB == res.length && ori[cntA] != '') res.push( ori[cntA], 1); // New element found then push it and start count
 }
 return res; // returns the agrouped array 0:element 1:instances...
}
```

If you don't want a count of instances, then you would need an even simpler function, you could try modify this one.